# Heat map with Highcharts and csv string data

Tags: string, csv, highcharts, heatmap

I would like to know how made a heat map with highcharts. I base it on this link http://jsfiddle.net/9pJhF/ but the format on my csv is something like that, i use for the X and Y axis the strings :

```
<pre id="csv" style="display: none">Col1, Col2, Col3
'Name1','A',3077
'Name2','B',5486
'Name3','A',377
'Name4','B',546
'Name5','A',77
'Name6','B',46
</pre>
```

I must changed the parameters  of X axis and Y axis but i don't know how do that.

I think it is something like that but i have an error : uncaught exception: Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14 because i have a string and not a integer.

```
xAxis: { categories : ['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5','Name6']}
yAxis: {tickPositions: ['A','B']}
```

So i would like a solution to use string in X and Y axis to do a heat map from a csv or directly in the highcharts data.